# anchorScroll with ionic modal cant get it working , How?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework, anchor-scroll

How do you use $ionicScrollDelegate with anchorScroll in ionic modal, I am able to make it  work with in angular App and also in ionic (without ionic modal),

In Angular:

working plunker with angular

```
   plnkr.co/edit/CQeaComH4xv2h2ckBudA?p=preview1
```

In ionic:

In this plunker i just tested with ionic modal and without ionic modal

when i start using same concept with ionic modal, i cant make it work. Is there anything i have to do to make it to work with ionic modal

plunker with ionic

```
plnkr.co/edit/ZN8pr20rUOB4QN17IwQh?p=preview
```

what i need is in my open start modal i need startView at 07:30 and in close model startView by 17:30,

(Note: these two functions are called in same controller in my application)

Any help much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: @admin, really sorry to post plunker like this, i tried to as described in help section ex:  ( [link](http://google.com) ), but it did not work, spent almost  hour with that.